# Underline Flex mx:Text on mouseover using external CSS

Tags: css, apache-flex

I have some text in a Flex 3 application defined as follows

```
<mx:Text id="textbutton" 
         text="Link Text" 
         click="doSomething()"
     styleName="linkText" 
         buttonMode="true" 
         useHandCursor="true" 
         mouseChildren="false"/>
```

And an external `CSS` declaration as follows:

```
.linkText {
/*  text-decoration:underline;*/
    color: #0000FF;
}

.linkText:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

It does not seem to work however as the text does not underline when I mouse over it.

Is there a way to do this purely through `CSS` or do I need to programmatically capture the mouse events and set the styles accordingly (seems like overkill)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this purely through CSS.  You need to catch roll over and roll out mouse events and switch styles on it from some `linkText` to `linkTextUnderlined` using `setStyle()` method.